# NSManagedObject cannot change attribute

Tags: ios, core-data

I am running into an issue with CoreData (using MagicalRecord) trying to change an attribute. I think this is the result of the object having relationships to two parent entities.

The object is a **manual**, this has a to-many relationship to both a **car** and **library**. The **library** contains all **manual** objects. A **car** has 1-3 **manual** items.

Every **manual** has a UID and the same object is shared between the **car** and **library**.

For some reason, once the object is set into the relationship for both, I cannot change the **title** (NSString) attribute of the **manual**.

I checked to make sure I am in the same context. Not sure what the issue is.

This is what I am logging:

```
NSLog(@"Manual Title: %@",manual.title);
 //prints Old Manual 

manual.title = @"New Manual"
NSLog(@"Manual Title: %@",manual.title);
 //prints New Manual
```

I'm saving this inside a MagicalRecord `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait` other unrelated NSManagedObjects in the same method are being saved.

When the app loads the data into the UI, it still reads "Old Manual"

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was two-fold with the MagicalRecord methods I was using:

1) Instead of `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait` I should have used `saveWithBlockAndWait`

2) When I was fetching the manual object, I wasn't passing the context, so I changed `MR_findFirstWithPredicate` to `MR_findFirstWithPredicate:inContext`

Hopefully this will save someone else some time